# Transform the circuit of combinational logic into a boolean expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

We have the following:

[image]

I want to transform this circuit of combinational logic into a boolean expression.

The circles mean the negation and the symbol that is used is the symbol for AND, or not?

To find that expression do we start from right to left?

Comment: I suggest starting at the output.  Anyway, is that last gate supposed to be a different type than the previous ones?  Never seen it before.  Also there is an electrical engineering stack exchange now.

Comment: @Mary Star     The final gate seems not to be an AND. Otherwise, the function would be $(\overline{x}yz)(\overline{x}\,\overline{y}z)$ which is clearly $0.$

Answer (score 0):

You can start from left. If there is single input NAND gate then you should assume the other input is absent that is 0. So the top most gate in left is **NOT**(0 AND $x$)=1
Similarly for bottom most gate it is also 1.

The final expression should be $f_{x,y,x}=yz$

Comment: Wouldn't a single input nand gate be a not gate?

Comment: when both input of NAND gate are joined together then it can function as NOT gate. Ideally, it should have been clearly indicated in question that a 0 or +ve input is applied. There are families of logic where you might assume an open input to have either a 1 or 0 as input.